# Looking for a Javascript alternative of Flash Image slideshow

Tags: javascript, flash

I am looking for a javascript based alternative of the following Flash based Image slideshow

http://osc4.template-help.com/joomla_30291/

Any idea where I can find that matches closes to this flash based solution?

Comment: almost all javascript libraries provide this, if u use jquery, u'll get immediate help here

Comment: Agree with MLS, I provided some nfo in my answer + links to some examples that should have him well on his way.

Comment: Thanks, I have used a plugin called Dj Image Slider which seems to be based on mootools. Had to add some custom css style but end results is the same as in the other template.  http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/images-slideshow/13119 Thanks everyone who helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between the following examples, you should be able to replicate the site provided:

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/gallery.html

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/multiple-scrollables.html

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/combine/portfolio/index.html

JqueryTools is a great addon/wrapper for jquery. You can also just pretty much google "***_*** + jquery" and get an example or addon for what you're looking to do.